# Ignore IPython magic in python

Tags: python, ipython, ipython-magic

What is the best way to ignore IPython magic when running scripts using the python interpreter?

I often include IPython magic in my script files because it work with the code interactively. For example, with the `autoreload` magic, I don't have to keep `reload`-ing the modules after I make some changes and fix bugs:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

However, when I try to run this script using a usual python interpreter, I get an error:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    %load_ext autoreload
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Wrapping IPython magic inside an `if` statement does not work, because incorrect syntax is detected before the file is actually ran.

---

So what is the best way to get python to ignore IPython magic?

It's annoying to have to change your scripts whenever you want to run then in python, pdb, sphinx, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all tools that can read from standard input you could use grep to remove any magic lines and pipe the result into python:

```
grep -v '^%' magicscript.ipy | python
```

Works well as a bash alias:

```
alias pynomagic='( grep -v "^%" | python ) < '
pynomagic magicscript.ipy
```

Tools like pdb that only accept filenames could be called like this (bash again):

```
pdb <(grep -v '^%' magicscript.ipy)
```

Comment: I am running my code inside the Spyder IDE using the `runfile` and `debugfile` commands, so `grep` does not really help, but it might be useful for someone else :).

Answer (score 3):

In case this helps anyone.

At least for Databricks, when syncing a notebook with a .py file in Github, a magic function can be specified with a specially formatted comment.
Like this:

`# MAGIC %run ./my_external_file`

Answer (score 2):

You should load such magic in your config file, *not* in your scripts! It is just not valid Python.

Put the following in your `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`:

```
c = get_config()
c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = ['autoreload']
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%autoreload 2']
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines.append('print("Warning: disable autoreload in ipython_config.py to improve performance.")')
```

Comment: Hmmm. I was hoping there would be a way to do this on a per-file basis. `autoreload` was just an example. There are cases where I make a plot using rpy2 magic, or save some sql code to a file using %%file magic. I just want python to ignore IPython code blocks.

Comment: @ostrokach One possible solution I thought up  was to write a script to replace the `python` command. This script would "clean" the files before handing them over to the "real" python. *But that would probably also affect IPython!* So that won't work. (Unless you could configure IPython to call the "real" python directly.) In the final analysis, IPython commands are just not valid Python.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a template file named `simplepython.tpl`. Copy the below statements.

   ```
   {% extends 'python.tpl'%}
   {% block codecell %}
   {{  super().replace('get_ipython','#get_ipython') if "get_ipython" in super() else super() }}
   {% endblock codecell %}
   ```
2. Save `simplepython.tpl`.
3. Type in command line:

   > jupyter nbconvert --to python 'IPY Notebook' --template=simplepython.tpl --stdout

Answer (score 0):

Spyder gives warning (as given in the picture below), when a coder use this type of code and says that it is not a valid Python code.

So, in order to use IPython magics,  saving files with the .ipy extension may be a solution.

[Spyder screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J45z9.png)